# Synchronize Between Listbox and Listview

Tags: c#

I have ListBox and listview, in one form, and I must synchronize between both of them, 
for example, if I select the first item in the list box, its must be selected, in the listview, and if I select an item from the list view, its must be selected in the ListBox.

I have success, to do it from the list box to the list view, but not for both of them,
I try to use flags, and that does not work.

My **ListBox** code is like this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    this.listView1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

And the **ListView** code is:

```
 private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.listBox1.SetSelected(this.listView1.FocusedItem.Index, true);
 }
```

Comment: Do you get error on this or this doesn't work?

Comment: You need to set the focused property to true as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try in my computer, and following code works:

```
namespace  WindowsFormsApplication5
    {
        public partial class Form4 : Form
        {
            public Form4()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
                listView1.ItemSelectionChanged += new ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(listView1_ItemSelectionChanged);
                listView1.Items.Add("3434");
                listView1.Items.Add("13434");
                listBox1.Items.Add("3434");
                listBox1.Items.Add("13434");
            }

            void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.listBox1.SetSelected(this.listView1.FocusedItem.Index, true);
            }

            void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.listView1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No , this is not working , when you select item from list view , its automatically selected in the listbox , the another side is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try use for list view

listView1.ItemSelectionChanged += new ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(listView1_ItemSelectionChanged);

```
    void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.listBox1.SetSelected(this.listView1.FocusedItem.Index, true);
    }
```

Comment: Error 1 No overload for 'listView1_SelectedIndexChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: you must remove listView1.SelectedIndexChanged+=new ListViewSelectedIndexChangedEventHandler(listView1_SelectedIndexChanged) in designer file.

Comment: no its not work , i have try the two solutions , and search google for some solution , and nothing work :)